# How to recover a 2D map with terrain-type (water, forest, plain ..) Google / Bing map?

Tags: c#, google-maps, geolocation, bing-maps, terrain

I wonder if it is possible to recover the **type of terrain** (mountains, forest, water, plain etc ...) on Google Maps or Bing Mag **on a 2D/3D map**. In order **to generate a map from the game player's position on the real world!**
I think it is possible with the number of available API google map and bing, but I do not know where to look ...

Here's an example I search

"location" : {
            "lat" : 39.73915360,
            "long" : -104.98470340}

[image]

Thank's a lot

Comment: You might be interested in Alastair's blog post: http://alastaira.wordpress.com/2012/03/14/creating-the-legend-of-zelda-map-tiles-from-bing-maps-aerial-imagery/

If you want to do this, you can also try to find Corine Land Cover data to be able to generate map without using a commercial platform not dedicated to this kind of usage.

Comment: Ohhh thank you very much! This seems to be what I want. I'll take a closer look! Can you turn this into an answer?

Comment: Done. Glad it can help you. Also, it could be great to add information about elevation (see Elevation service: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj158959.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be interested in, my fellow, Alastair's blog post:

http://alastaira.wordpress.com/2012/03/14/creating-the-legend-of-zelda-map-tiles-from-bing-maps-aerial-imagery/

[image: Bing Maps 8 Bit map by Alastair Aitchison]

If you want to do this, you can also try to find Corine Land Cover data to be able to generate map without using a commercial platform not dedicated to this kind of usage.

Comment: Thanks Nicolas Boonaert ;-)